# Create a class modules with parent and child classes in VBA

Tags: vba

I am a novice user of class module.

I don't understand the concept of a class module well.

I want to configure a class module similar to the basic objects of Excel like Worksheet or Cells or ETC..
So I want to control it by creating a parent object and creating its child objects.

**Child Class - Defect**

```
Option Explicit

Private pDefectSymptom As String
Private pDefectLevel As Integer

Property Get DefectSymptom() As String
    DefectSymptom = pDefectSymptom
End Property

Property Let DefectSymptom(ByVal vDefectSymptom As String)
    pDefectSymptom = vDefectSymptom
End Property

Property Get DefectLevel() As Integer
    DefectLevel = pDefectLevel

End Property

Property Let DefectLevel(ByVal vDefectLevel As Integer)
    pDefectLevel = vDefectLevel

End Property

Function Delete()
    '???
End Function

Property Get Parent() As Object
    '???
End Property
```

**Parent Class - Defects**

```
Private Defects As New Collection

Function Add(DefectSymptom As String, Optional DefectLevel As Integer) As Defect

    Dim NewDefect As Defect
    
    Set NewDefect = New Defect
    
    NewDefect.DefectSymptom = DefectSymptom
    NewDefect.DefectLevel = DefectLevel

    Defects.Add NewDefect
    
    'Add = NewDefect  'Error! Like the open command of workbook, I want to return an object or just command
End Function

Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = Defects.Count
End Property

Property Get Item(Index As Long) As Defect
    Item = Defects(Index) 'Error! I don't know what raise Error.
End Property
```

My question are.

1. How to add Command like Open Command of workbook. Return or just command.
2. Why Raise Error Item Property? how to fix that?
3. Hiding Private variable. Because office office objects seem to be hidden.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7fGz.png)
4. If you have time, please help with Delete command and Parent command.

Answer (score 1):

> How to add Command like Open Command of workbook. Return or just
> command.

You just need to return the newly created object in the function. Keep in mind since we're dealing with objects, we need to `Set` the object's reference.

```
Public Function Add(DefectSymptom As String, Optional DefectLevel As Integer) As Defect

    Dim NewDefect As Defect
    Set NewDefect = New Defect
    
    NewDefect.DefectSymptom = DefectSymptom
    NewDefect.DefectLevel = DefectLevel

    Defects.Add NewDefect
    
    Set Add = NewDefect  '<- here
End Function
```

> Why Raise Error Item Property? how to fix that?

Same as the above, you need to `Set` the object's reference.

```
Property Get Item(Index As Long) As Defect
    Set Item = Defects(Index) 
End Property
```

To delete, simply supply the index to the function. However, this method must reside where the collection is (parent) since a `Defect` object cannot delete itself.

```
Function Delete(ByVal Index As Long)
    Defects.Remove Index
End Function
```

Lastly, to hold a reference to the parent, each child must hold a reference to it in a private variable. Then you need to set the parent when creating a new item using the keyword `Me`.

So in the `Defect` class, create a private field.

```
Private mParent As Defects

Property Set Parent(ByVal objDefects As Defects)
    Set mParent = objDefects 
End Property

Property Get Parent() As Defects
    Set Parent = mParent
End Property
```

With this done, amend the `Add()` method to store the reference.

```
Public Function Add(DefectSymptom As String, Optional DefectLevel As Integer) As Defect

    Dim NewDefect As Defect
    Set NewDefect = New Defect
    
    NewDefect.DefectSymptom = DefectSymptom
    NewDefect.DefectLevel = DefectLevel
    Set NewDefect.Parent = Me '<- here

    Defects.Add NewDefect
    
    Set Add = NewDefect  '<- here
End Function
```

Not sure this is a good idea though. I tend to avoid circular references altogether, since a child can hold the parent in memory by holding a reference to it. You will need to make sure to clear the reference to the Parent when deleting the item.

Lastly, you should avoid creating the `Defects` collection like this. Instead, you should make use of the class constructor and destructor.

This method is called automatically when a new class is created:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Defects = New VBA.Collection
End Sub
```

This method is called just before the class is destroyed from memory.

```
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set Defects = Nothing
End Sub
```